# java mysql foreign key constraint

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

So I selected some values from a database table to divide them in little groups and insert it into another table within the database but I have no clue on how to do that I tried so many ways. I managed to divide them in little groups and I want to insert them in another table. but I can only add the values to the table without dividing them. any help would be appreciated. this my code.

```
    private void spelersVerdelenMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             


    String comboBoxValue = jComboBoxDeelnemer.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String spelerRonde1 = "SELECT lid, toernooi FROM deelnemer where     toernooi LIKE " + comboBoxValue ; 


    ArrayList<String> dlnmrs = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

      PreparedStatement pstat = con.prepareStatement(spelerRonde1);
      ResultSet rs = pstat.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {

            dlnmrs.add(rs.getString("lid"));
            for (int i = 0; i < dlnmrs.size(); i++) {
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,e);
    }



    verdeelTafels(1, dlnmrs.size()); 


    private void verdeelTafels(int ronde, int aantalDeelnemers) {

    System.out.println(aantalDeelnemers);

    int aantalTafels = (int) aantalDeelnemers / AANTAL_SPELERS_PER_TAFEL;
    int restSpelerPerRonde = aantalDeelnemers % AANTAL_SPELERS_PER_TAFEL;

    if (aantalDeelnemers == (AANTAL_SPELERS_PER_TAFEL * 2)) {
        aantalTafels = 1;
        restSpelerPerRonde = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < aantalTafels; i++) {
        int maxSpelersPerTafel = AANTAL_SPELERS_PER_TAFEL;
        if (i == aantalTafels - 1) {
            maxSpelersPerTafel += restSpelerPerRonde;
        }
        System.out.println("Tafel " + (i + 1) + " heeft " + maxSpelersPerTafel + " deelnemers.");

        //spelersDoorlopen

        for (int j = 0; j < maxSpelersPerTafel; j++) {


      String query = "insert into spelerPerTafel (lid,tafel,ronde) select lcode,tfcode,rcode from lid,tafel,ronde ";
     try{ 
             PreparedStatement pstat = con.prepareStatement(query);


             pstat.execute(query);
          }
        catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,e);
            System.out.println(e);
          } 

        }

      }

}
```

Comment: this is a sql error try printing query variable in your console then copy the query and run to your database gui

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use SELECT statements inside VALUES statement part.

Rewrite your SQL query to  [INSERT SELECT statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you read carefully your query:

```
"insert into spelerPerTafel (lid,tafel,ronde,toernooi) VALUES( "+maxSpelersPerTafel+","+i+",0,1 "+" (SELECT lcode,tfcode FROM tafel))"
```

You are missing a comma between the last 1 and the openning parenthesis for the subselect and even if you add the missing comma, you are inserting 5 values (maxSpelersPerTafel, i, 9, 1, subselect) when you only stated four columns to be inserted (lid,tafel,ronde,toernooi).